# tf::TransformListener gets wrong tf

Tags: rviz, rosbag, clock, tf2, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

TL;DR tf::TransformListener gets a different transform than shown in RVIZ

I am having quite a strange problem. I am using a rosbag file to playback recorded data and I am adding new transforms and using them while doing that:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
rosbag play 2016-09-12-14-51-41.bag --clock
```

The transform is published with a python node, where the origin is static (defined with cfg-values) and the rotation is coming from the values of an IMU. The interesting part how the tf is published should be this (in the callback of the IMU subscription):

```
  br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
  br.sendTransform((frame_offset_x, frame_offset_y, frame_offset_z),
               quaternion,
               rospy.Time.now(),
               frame_child,
               frame_parent
              )
```

With the following values:

```
  frame_offset_x = 0
  frame_offset_y = 0
  frame_offset_z = 1.2
  quaternion = rotation of the IMU (only around the x and y axis)
  frame_child = level_laser_2
  frame_parent = base_footprint
```

The created Transform in RVIZ looks like expected. It's 1.2m above base_footprint with some rotation on top.
In the picture, the Fixed Frame is set to "base_footprint"

[image: level_tf in RVIZ]

However if I lookup the transform in a ROS node using the tf::TransformListener I get a different result:

```
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
...
  tf_listener_ = new tf::TransformListener( ros::Duration(10) ); // in the constructor
...
void callback( const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Ptr& cloud_in ) {
  ...
  if ( tf_listener_->waitForTransform(tf_target_,
                                      cloud_in->header.frame_id,
                                      cloud_in->header.stamp,
                                      ros::Duration( scan_time_ )) ) {
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    tf_listener_->lookupTransform(tf_target_,
                                  cloud_in->header.frame_id,
                                  cloud_in->header.stamp,
                                  transform);
    ROS_INFO("%s %s -> %s\tat%lf", node_name_.c_str(),
                                   cloud_in->header.frame_id.c_str(),
                                   tf_target_.c_str(),
                                   cloud_in->header.stamp.toSec());

    tfScalar tf[16];
    transform.getOpenGLMatrix(tf);

    ROS_INFO("%s\n"
             "/ %lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf \\\n"
             "| %lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf |\n"
             "| %lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf |\n"
             "\\ %lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf /", node_name_.c_str(),
             tf[0], tf[4], tf[8], tf[12],
             tf[1], tf[5], tf[9], tf[13],
             tf[2], tf[6], tf[10], tf[14],
             tf[3], tf[7], tf[11], tf[15]);
  } else {
    // display error here 
  }
  ...
}
```

The output of this is:

```
[ INFO] [1473756806.521699009, 1473684710.202103154]: /level_laser_velodyne:  base_footprint -> level_laser_2 at1473684709.395050
[ INFO] [1473756806.521764836, 1473684710.202103154]: /level_laser_velodyne: 
/ 0.997645  0.001908    -0.068567   0.002741 \
| 0.001908  0.998454    0.055557    -0.002221 |
| 0.068567  -0.055557   0.996098    -0.039822 |
\ 0.000000  0.000000    0.000000    1.000000 /
```

But it should be something like:

```
[ INFO] [1473756806.521764836, 1473684710.202103154]: /level_laser_velodyne: 
/ R R R 0 \
| R R R 0 |
| R R R 1.2 |
\ 0 0 0 1 /
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help,
Tobias

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243653/tf::transformlistener-gets-wrong-tf/) by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2016-09-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not solved, but I've found a workaround by using a different node and therefore I'm closing this question.

I'm sorry that I can't help someone running into the same problem and ending up at this question.

---

Originally posted by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) with karma: 179 on 2018-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you need to swap target and source frames in `lookupTransform`.

I know it is confusing, but I guess the way to think about it is that `lookupTransform` returns a way of *transforming* data from `source_frame` to `target_frame`.
So if you want to know where `child` is relative to its `parent`, `parent` is the target frame, because you want to express the position and orientation of `child` while looking from `parent`'s frame.

---

Originally posted by [artifactz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22331/artifactz/) with karma: 119 on 2018-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2018-11-07**:
Thank you, that might've be wrong as well. But I would have expected a translation of 1.2m, instead I got something around 4cm.

However since this question is over 2 years old, I solved it a different way.